# How do I pre-select an option in my Rails f.select item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, html-select

I'm using Rails 5.  I want to pre-select an option in my form.  The field from my model is a boolean but obviously the options (texts and values) are strings.  So I tried this

```
<%= f.select :bool_field, options_for_select([["Above", "false"], ["Below", "true"]]), @my_event.nil? ? nil : @my_event.bool_field.to_s, {:prompt => "Select Object"} %>
```

but I'm getting a

> undefined method `merge' for "false":String

error when the page renders.  What's the proper way to pre-select an option in my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parenthesis is wrong:

```
<%= f.select :bool_field, options_for_select([["Above", "false"], ["Below", "true"]], @my_event.nil? ? nil : @my_event.bool_field.to_s), {:prompt => "Select Object"} %>
```